# Why does SSRS taking too long to execute in design and more while building it?

Tags: sql, performance, reporting-services

I have two data-sets in my SSRS tool, first table contain 12,000 records and second one 26,000 records. And 40 columns in each table.

While building a report each time I go preview - it takes forever to display.
Is any way to do something to avoid that, so I can at least not spent so much time to build this report?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is also the option to not validate the connection. Sorry can't check just now

Comment: Does your query work in SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

Add a dummy parameter to limit your dataset. Or just change your `select` to `select top 100` while building the report

Answer (score 0):

@vercelli's answer is a good one. In addition you can change your cache options in the designer (for all resultsets including patramters) so that the queries are not rerun each time.

This is really useful plus - a couple of tips for you:
1. I don't recommend caching until you are happy with the your dataset results.
2. If you are using the cache and you want to do a quick refresh then the data is stored in a ".data" file in the same location as a your .rdl. You can delete this to query the database again if required.

Comment: The report has pretty complex calculations. And its a giant report.
I think caching it would be my the only option?

Comment: You're missing the point - "I don't recommend caching until you are happy with the your dataset results" **is not the same as** "I don't recommend caching until you are happy with the your report design"!